# $error = 404 after caught add_rewrite_rule

Tags: 404-error, rewrite-rules, post-status

I have a rewrite rule as this to caught old urls from a previous version of the site:

```
add_rewrite_rule( '(ninos|familia|hogar|mujeres|hombres)-[a-z-]+\.php', 'old_id_redirect.php', 'top' );
```

The rewrite rule works more or less as intended, and I see in the debugger that the request goes through `old_id_redirect.php`.

In there, there is only (so far) a call to `wp-blog-header.php`, and nothing and almost nothing else.

I stop execution just after that there to see the enviroment state, and I see that `$error` is set to "404".

Why is that? If the add_rewrite_rule was caught and the redirection made, why is `$error` is set to 404?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found a solution. From what I learned so far, there might be two causes to this problem:

1. WP doesn't recognize your rewrite rules because they are not cached yet. You can check this by dumping `get_option( 'rewrite_rules' );` and if your rules did get cached, then they'll be in that option. To ensure your rewrite rules are cached, make sure you call:

   ```
   global $wp_rewrite; 
   $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
   ```
2. Your server configuration is not properly set to use `.htaccess` files (for Apache servers). An easy way to check is to type a URL address that doesn't exist after your WordPress host, e.g. `http://example.com/location-that-doesnt-exist`. If your server is properly configured to use `.htaccess` files, then you'll see a 404 page styled by your WP theme. If it is NOT properly set, then you will see the server's default 404 page and it will not be styled by your WP theme.